# Powershell - remove currency formatting from a number

Tags: powershell, formatting, currency

can you please tell me how to remove currency formatting from a variable (which is probably treated as a string).

How do I strip out currency formatting from a variable and convert it to a true number?

Thank you.

example

```
PS C:\Users\abc> $a=($464.00)
PS C:\Users\abc> "{0:N2}" -f $a
                         <- returns blank
```

However

```
PS C:\Users\abc> $a=-464
PS C:\Users\abc> "{0:C2}" -f $a
($464.00)                 <- this works
```

Comment: PowerShell, the programming language, does not "know" what money or currency is - everything PowerShell sees is a variable name (`$464`) and a property reference (`.00`) that doesn't exist, so `$a` ends up with no value.

Comment: Edit: Source variable can be negative, in this format ($464.00) or positive in which case it can be $1,234.00. Basically as currency formatted by excel. Need to convert it to a proper decimal. Thanks,

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen got it.. can you provide any solution?

Comment: `$a = ($464.00)` - do you mean `$a = "$464.00"` (i.e., a string containing a number formatted as a currency)? And why are you adding `(` and `)` around it?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that's because it's a negative number and that's how excel formats those when using currency formatting. Thanks,

Comment: You're confusing what Excel displays and PowerShell syntax. You're actually talking about taking a string formatted as an Excel-like currency number and interpreting it as numeric value in PowerShell. What is provoking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell, the programming language, does not "know" what money or currency is - everything PowerShell sees is a variable name (`$464`) and a property reference (`.00`) that doesn't exist, so `$a` ends up with no value.

If you have a string in the form: `$00.00`, what you can do programmatically is:

```
# Here is my currency amount
$mySalary = '$500.45'

# Remove anything that's not either a dot (`.`), a digit, or parentheses:
$mySalary = $mySalary -replace '[^\d\.\(\)]'

# Check if input string has parentheses around it
if($mySalary -match '^\(.*\)$')
{
    # remove the parentheses and add a `-` instead
    $mySalary = '-' + $mySalary.Trim('()')
}
```

So far so good, now we have the string `500.45` (or `-500.45` if input was `($500.45)`).

Now, there's a couple of things you can do to convert a string to a numerical type.

You could explicitly convert it to a `[double]` with the `Parse()` method:

```
$mySalaryNumber = [double]::Parse($mySalary)
```

Or you could rely on PowerShell performing an implicit conversion to an appropriate numerical type with a unary `+`:

```
$mySalaryNumber = +$mySalary
```

Comment: Ok great - almost there. Can you provide a snippet to convert negatives as well. ($464.00) to -464.00. That's all I need. Thanks very much.

Comment: will try ASAP. Thanks very much.

Comment: This worked, I dont know how to accept a particular solution from the website as a "solution", but it's all good! Thank you Mathias!