# Convert number to currency

Tags: powershell, currency-formatting

We need to convert a plain number to a currency value. However, nothing we find seems to work.

We tried the basic code below, but that returns a value of $123,456.00 when it should be $1,234.56.

```
$rawNumber = 123456
$newNumber = 0

$newNumber = "{0:c}" -f $rawNumber
```

We tried different iterations of "{0:c}" (c2, c1,etc), but it always returns a number, but just adding zeroes on to the end.

We tried converting the number to a string and inserting the decimal, commas and dollar sign, but we're dealing with numbers that can be as short as two or as long as ten, so it becomes something of a beast to try and plan for every possible combination.

Are we missing something obvious to easily convert numbers to a currency value?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Possible (reverse) duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484818/powershell-remove-currency-formatting-from-a-number

Comment: @LotPings Yes and no... mostly in the sense that computers can't know what meaning we impose on strings and numbers unless we actually tell the computer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a subdivision of the primary unit of a currency, you need to divide the input value to get the number of primary units, in this case:

```
$dollars = $rawNumber / 100
$formattedString = '{0:C}' -f $dollars
```

---

Beware that the resulting formatted string will depend on the current locale. You can pass a `[cultureinfo]` object to the `ToString()` method of the target object instead if you want a specific locale enforced. Here shown with `en-US`, `de-DE` and `da-DK`:

```
PS C:\> 'en-US','de-DE','da-DK' |ForEach-Object { $dollars.ToString('C',[cultureinfo]$_) }
$1,234.56
1.234,56 €
1.234,56 kr.
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that the format string operator will apply the current locale settings, here with a German locale `$formattedString` contains `1.234,56 €`

Answer (score 3):

You can format the input using `{0:C2}` the `2` in `C2` is the amount of decimal places.

Example:

```
$rawNumber = 123456
$newNumber = 0

$newNumber = "{0:C2}" -f $rawNumber
```

Comment: While this does add the dollar sign to the front of the number, it's still producing a number that simply has zeroes added on to the end: $123,456.00.

Comment: updated for the correct format. @MathiasR.Jessen answer is much more diverse -- upvote